# I can't refit the sump on a Miele G6510 dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

In order to replace the heater element on my Miele G6510 dishwasher, I removed the whole sump assembly by removing the large worm-band and removing the filter and unscrewing the washer-jet mount.
(I now know that this is not necessary - you can remove the circulation motor by just prising it out!).

When I try to reattach the sump I can not fit it over the large seal. The service manual simply says "Use rinse-agent" to lubricate it. I've tried washing up liquid without success.

I've tried all sort of ways to force it but I can't seem to apply enough pressure.

P.S. The heater element is included in the replacement part "Pump Facia"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably that the o-ring has deformed making it impossible to refit.

Unfortunately, Miele only sells the o-ring as part of a new sump assembly, which costs over £50 and has to be ordered from Germany.

Fortunately, a British Standard 169.10mm inner-dimension, 185.90mm out-dimension, 8.40mm cross-section o-ring seems to be a perfect replacement.

One such supplier is https://www.altecweb.com/ product code: ORN-1691-84